# Specify chrome absolute repository URL behind corporate proxy when installing puppeteer in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome, repository, puppeteer

When trying to install the latest version of puppeteer 20.4.0 the url that our corporate proxy uses for chrome driver it's something like this

```
https://custom.cache.repository.com/repository/googleapis-storage/chromedriver/113.0.5672.63/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip
```

but puppeteer is trying to resolve to this URL

```
https://custom.cache.repository.com/repository/googleapis-storage/chromedriver/113.0.5672.63/mac-arm64/chrome-mac-arm64.zip
```

which does not exists

I'm using this in the .npmrc file

```
puppeteer_skip_download=false
puppeteer_download_base_url=https://custom.cache.repository.com/repository/googleapis-storage/chromedriver
```

The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:16.1.0

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY package*.json .npmrc ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

USER node
```

Is there a way to specify the absolute URL of the chrome driver .zip?